# Cohomology of certain arithmetic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, arithmetic-groups

This is a question on literature about cohomology of arithmetic groups.
Let $M$ denote a quaternion algebra over $\mathbb Q$ and assume it is non-split over $\mathbb R$. Fix a maximal order $\Lambda$ in $M$ and for any ring $R$ let
$$
M(R)=\Lambda\otimes_{\mathbb Z}R,\qquad G(R)=M(R)^\times/R^\times.
$$
Let $p$ be a prime number at which $M$ splits and set 
$$
\Gamma_p=G({\mathbb Z}[1/p])
$$
 I need to know how the first Betti-number 
$$
\dim H^1(\Gamma_p,{\mathbb C}),
$$
depends on $p$. I would be grateful if you could point me towards some literature on this.

Comment: Isn't $H^0(\Gamma_p,\mathbb C)$ just $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @Will Sawin: Yes indeed, you may replace $\mathbb C$ with a finite-dimensional representation of the rational points, but I am mainly interested in the case of the trivial representation.

Comment: Regardless, that term won't depend on $p$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can write $G(\mathbb Q_p)/ G(\mathbb Z_p) =GL_2(\mathbb Q_p)/GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ as the set of vertices of a tree (the Bruhat-Tits tree) of degree $p+1$.

The group $\Gamma_p$ acts on this tree with finite stabilizers. Hence the cohomology of the quotient $\Gamma_p \backslash G(\mathbb Q_p)/ G(\mathbb Z_p) $ is equal to the group cohomology of $\Gamma_p$.

That's some graph with $n$ vertices and at most $n(p+1)/2$ edges, where $n$ is the cardinality of $\Gamma_p \backslash G(\mathbb Q_p)/ G(\mathbb Z_p) $, and thus Euler characteristic at least $-n (p-1)/2$ (and at most $1$).

$n$ is bounded independently of $p$ because any class in $G(\mathbb Q_p)/G(\mathbb Z_p)$ defines a locally free left $M(\mathbb Z)$-submodule inside $M(\mathbb Z[1/p])$, with two modules $\Gamma_p$-conjugate if and only if they are isomorphic, and because there are finitely many isomorphism classes of locally free left $M(\mathbb Z)$-modules.

Comment: Is the Euler characteristic dependent on $p$?

Comment: I understand the computation in the case of trivial stabilizers, but for finite stabilizers? Imagine the case of a finite group acting trivially on a point.

Comment: @Corbennick Yes, the Euler characteristic depends on $p$ in general because the number of edges does in fact grow. For finite stabilizers, the point is we are taking cohomology with coefficients in a characteristic zero field, and use the fact that cohomology of a finite group with coefficients in a characteristic zero field is trivial. A simple way to do it for this problem is use the Bass-Serre explicit presentation in terms of the quotient and stabilizers, calculate the homomorphisms to $\mathbb C$, and note that the answer is independent of the (finite) stabilizers.